# samba: config issues

Tags: windows-xp, samba, fedora

Am trying to add a samba server to my home LAN. Several problems are emerging:

1) When I try to 'net view \<server>  it appears to be routing to a machine outside the local network. Everything is in the 192.168.1 space and my 'ping <server>' is returning a system in the 208.67 space

2) When I try to 'net view \<IP address> of my samba server I get 'access denied'.

3) 2) When I try to 'net use * \<IP address>\<my folder> of my samba server with an account that I can use to SSH to the machine it doesn't recognize it.

Im new to the smb.conf settings so its clear that Im missing several steps.

When I do 'testparm' I get this:

```
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE
Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

[global]
    workgroup = HOME
    server string = Samba Server Version %v
    interfaces = lo, eth0
    passdb backend = tdbsam
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 50
    os level = 33
    dns proxy = No
    wins support = Yes
    hosts allow = 192.168.1., 127.0.0.1
    cups options = raw

[homes]
    comment = Home Directories
    valid users = %S
    read only = No

[printers]
    comment = All Printers
    path = /var/spool/samba
    printable = Yes
    browseable = No
```

Suggestions on what all is wrong? Am attemping connections from WinXP and Vista. OS is Fedora 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samba server on linux in default configuration uses its own password manager.

This is probably to ensure no standard system users are allowed access to the filesystem being shared without you knowing who they are. Please don't quote me on this.

To get an account to be recognised you must add it to samba, use smbpasswd on the samba server.

Code: smbpasswd (username)
Where username is the username you wish to connect to. This user must exist on the local system (ie: you can SSH into this user).

See: "man smbpasswd" for more details.

This should allow you access to your shares via the username you wish to use.

Note: you must be a privileged user on the machine to use smbpasswd.

Comment: smbpasswd allowed me to do the 'net use' command. Once I have a valid connection I can do the 'net view'. If I don't have a valid connection I still can't 'net view'. So we're sneaking up on the answer.

Comment: what name reolution service are you using? do you have reverse DNS on your network? or relying on netbios or other windows based naming systems?

Comment: Also - can you be specific to the command you're using for "net use \\server\path" (can you copy and paste)? Unless the name of the server cannot be provided? Also be sure to use two backslashes to denote server.. 

Sorry for the poor help, I'm a linux person, not a windows person.

Comment: its a small home network so no fancy DNS.. command is 'net view \\lk' or 'net use * \\lk\bunny'

Comment: The command you are using looks fine.. What is the result of "ping lk" on the windows machine?

Comment: Gives me the 'outside' (208.67) address.

Comment: Further thoughts are: All your problems now come down to name resolution. Depending on your ISP you may have an annoying one which wishes to employ DNS hijacking: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_hijacking ... This means if your client machine cannot find the server by name through other channels it will fall back to DNS which the ISP then hijacks to redirect you to a search engine to "help" you find what you're looking for.

Comment: Are you using static IP addresses on the server? If so you can resolve this by simply using the IP address in the connect to command or you can add an entry into the client machines hosts file (unix, linux, macosx and windows all use a hosts file). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file .

In this file you can put on a new line "<ip> <name>" to force a specific name resolution, DO NOT EDIT ANY EXISTING LINES unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: Typically, hosts files are searched first before DNS, NetBIOS or WINS. This file can be found in c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts (winxp) - edit this with notepad.exe or similar text editor. It does not have a file extension and shouldn't have one. 

This solution is not good if you don't have static IP addresses, you will need to look into another naming service.

Comment: Sorry for all the comments.. Hope this helps!

Comment: Its a great number of possible directions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using `valid users = %S' seems not suitable. %S means "Name of the service" like the share name.

Take a look in at the man page of [smb.conf](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html), where all variable explained.

If you are not familar with pitfalls of intergrating the windows and unix world, you should read some helpfull documents:

- http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/
- http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/

For Standalone Server take a look here: http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/FastStart.html#id2554221

Comment: In this doc 'http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-samba-servers.html' towards the bottom there is a reference to this syntax.

Comment: @ethrbunny Ok, thats right and this will run correctly. I miss that the **home** share is a special one. The sharename is the username, so this is ok. What you need is a lokal unis **and** samba user with the **same** name as the windowsuser on the external windows box.